# Backbone.js How to track logged in user status and general advice on app structure

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I was wondering how can I track the current logged in user in a backbone.js app, Most of the views on the page need to know if the user is logged in or now and which user is logged in. What is the best method to achieve this?

I have session management on the server but how do I know which user am I dealing with in my backbone app and how do I know if he logged out thats the question

Also how do I know that a user has logged out using another tab etc? There should be a generic way to handle this stuff, like we have before filters in rails to manage such things. What method is used to achieve the same on the front end.

What I am currently doing is that when the homepage loads I have set from my server side rendered html a hidden field #current_user_id, which the my backbone app reads and sets a variable like the follwoing

```
window.MyApp =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}
  currentUser: null
  init: -> 
    @currentBusiness = $('#current_business').val()
    new MyApp.Routers.Businesses
    Backbone.history.start()

$(document).ready ->
  MyApp.init()
```

Then my router sets up a ShowView which then sets ups other sub views on the page

```
class MyApp.Routers.AppRouter extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    '': 'show'

  show: ->
    user = new Vocallocal.Models.user id: Vocallocal.currentBusiness
    Vocallocal.currentBusiness = business
    new Vocallocal.Views.BusinessesIndex model: business
    business.fetch()
```

Here is the main ShowView

```
class MyApp.Views.ShowView extends Backbone.View 

  el: '#main'
  template: JST['users/home'] 

  initialize: ->
    @model.bind 'change', @render, @
    @details = new Vocallocal.Views.UserDetails model: @model 
    @logo = new Vocallocal.Views.UserLogo model: @model 
    @managePhotos = new Vocallocal.Views.ManagePhotos model: @model 

  render: -> 
    console.log('change has occured') 
   @
```

does the above code and setup makes sense. I am looking on general advice if I should make any changes to the above.

Thank you for you valuable input

--Abid

Comment: Any sort of secure "logged in" status must be maintained via a server-side session. There is absolutely no way to do that securely at the client (that is, in JavaScript in the browser).

Comment: Yes I know that I have session management on the server but how do I know which user am I dealing with in my backbone app and how do I know if he logged out thats the question

Comment: Pointy is right, you really must secure your api server side. If you are doing that with session management/cookies then you should be able to read the session cookie on the client side and if the cookie is not present then the user is not logged in.

Comment: Can't you make the user information that part of the data model?

Comment: @Pointy yes thats what I am currently doing, the user information is part of the User model which I fetch initially by setting the id from the hidden variable and doing a model.fetch()

Comment: Right - so then every server interaction after that point (particularly those that persist changes) must also check the session, and when the session expires or ends those should return some sort of failure indication.

Comment: yes I can setup the server to send the response if the session has expired. Is the initial setup ok ? putting in hidden field and getting from there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also battled wrapping my head around authentication when developing client side apps. If you have ever worked with a 3rd party API (Facebook, Twitter) you will know that all authentication is done on the server side. Thats why @Pointy is correct. No authentication is done client side.

So If you are looking to access a secure part of your API, your username and password must be sent with every request, and checked on the server. This is definitely not the most secure way, and there are very few ways to get around this without an HTTPS connection. I am not sure what language you are developing your API in, but still this [link](http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/basic-authentication-with-asp-net-webapi/) is a very good read. Steve basically uses a simple protocol whereby the client sends an authorization token as a header in the HTTP request, and the server decodes that token to decide whether or not it is valid.

In answering your question, I would check if the user is valid. If he/she is, bootstrap your user model with an authentication token. This authentication token will be sent and decoded with every api request that requires authentication. I am no expert, so if there is any other way, please let me know. I am also still learning this.

Answer (score 2):

Our app is a fully separated client/server API architecture, including login.

When a user authenticates and authorizes with our server we send a JSON request with the relevant data over an HTTPS connection (this means due to CORS & IE, that our backend and our front end have to be served from the same site).

The backend returns an auth token.

Every authentication-required REST API requires this token to be sent along as an Authorization header over an HTTPS AJAX request.  The server is set to reject any tokens not provided by our mechanism, and reject any connections from pages which aren't served by our severs.

We store this auth token in a cookie on the client side.  If the auth token is invalid, missing, etc, our server returns an HTTP 401 which we trap and redirect the client to the login page if it occurs.