# few questions on backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

https://gist.github.com/1026406

I was going through this piece of code, and i have a few questions. Can some one explain me over this.

```
window.LoginView = new LoginView({model: new Credentials()});
```

1. Can anyone explain me what does the above code do... Will my
   `LoginView` instance have model as `Credentials`. If so, there is
   nothing i am doing with the `Credential`.

   var Credentials = Backbone.Model.extend({});
2. How can i call my REST Service. I don't want to use `form action`,
   instead can i call the `authenticate service` from my JS code which
   would return me some `flag`. On submitting my JS would collect the username and password and send it to `REST Service`.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `LoginView` is initialized with an empty `Credentials` model that will be updates when the inputs change (nb. the `this.username.change(..)` and `this.password.change(...)` binds).
2. The Backbone way of calling your REST service is to set the url property of your model like this `url: "path/to/the/rest/service/tied/to/my/model"` or by declaring the url as a function that returns the desired path string like this  `url: function() { ... return pathToMyRestService; }`. Then the REST service can be called with the model's [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) and [save](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) methods.

The other way is to use jQuery ajax methods, `ajax`, `post` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at gist provided, the credentials are being set inside the login method. So the LoginView is supplied a new Credentials model. Inside the Login method, the username and password are being set to the Credentials Model. Now when you call this.model.save() after credentials have been set, the model will be sent to the server. On the server you are able to then retrieve the username and password from your Credentials Model. I think there is a better way to authenticate a user though. A basic look at REST [Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071512/backbone-js-how-to-track-logged-in-user-status-and-general-advice-on-app-structu/11085953#11085953).